# in a system of Linear equations why is the inequality in the numbers of equations to that of the unknowns give me a no or an infinite solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

From my understanding, in a given linear system represented by $Ax=b$, $A$ is the amount of each vectors, $x$ the vectors making up the system and $b$ the vector that I'm trying to reach through my set of $x$.

If I was given $2$ equations with $ 3$ unknowns then the $b$ I'm trying to reach has $2$ dimensions, which is not representable by a $3d$ vector?
On the other hand, if I was given three equations with only two unknowns wouldn't be like trying to reach a $3d$ vector from $2d$ vectors?

Somehow this would give me an infinite set of solutions?